# Running a cron job randomly for every one hour

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I want a cronjob to run every one hour randomly. (i.e if the first job runs at 58 minutes,the second job should run at 47 minutes and the third one at 52 minutes and so on) But this should run randomly for everyone hour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by defining a job which runs every hour on the hour, and sleeps for a random amount of time before running the command you're actually interested in. In your crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

0 * * * * sleep $((RANDOM*3600/32768)) && command
```

(You need to specify the shell, to ensure that `$RANDOM` is available. There are other ways of getting a random value for `sleep` if that's not appropriate.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try it and let you know shortly.

Comment: Will it exactly runs 1hour once? I tried it seems to run once in an hour exactly, but not randomly like 54 minutes, 46 minutes, so on.

Comment: The cron job itself will run every hour on the hour exactly, but `command` within the cron job will run at some random minute in the hour.

Comment: Could you explain this part, what is going on heree? $((RANDOM*3600/32768))

Comment: @user3128796, reading `RANDOM` gives a randomly-selected integer between 0 and 32767. Multiplying that by 3600 and dividing by 32768 results in an integer between 0 and 3599, and interpreting that in seconds gives a duration between nothing and just under one hour.