# Cron */6 hours but with an offset?

Tags: cron

I have a bunch of devices all running a similar cron job. Currently I'm setting a cron minute and hours to a random number (that way they don't all run at once).

```
$random_minute $random_hour * * * sudo /bin/script
```

I want to keep this pattern of making each device random but I also have a script which needs to be run every 6 hours. How can I combine something like above with `*/6`?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Running a cron job randomly for every one hour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286599/86440).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't that many hours in the day, so why not just

```
17 3,9,15,21 * * * sudo /bin/script
```

to run at 03:17 and every 6 hours hence?

The alternatives would involve adding a sleep to the program itself:

```
0 */6 * * * (sleep 11820; sudo /bin/script)
```

or running the script more often (say, hourly), and having the script just exit if the actual job was executed within the last < 6 hours.

Comment: hmm, yes and I guess if I want to do that programmatically I can get a random number between 0-5, then `$random + 6, $random + 12, $random + 18`.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, hmm, yes. Though for multiple (almost) identical systems it would probably be easier to keep the crontabs identical, and use some method within the script to choose the delay...

Comment: Or something like `sleep $(< /etc/cron.delay) ; sudo /bin/script` in the crontab...

Answer (score 4):

With some `cron` implementations, you can use:

```
17 3-23/6 * * * * some command
```